# ERROR(<class 'samba.provision.ProvisioningError'>): Provision failed

Tags: server, samba

```
[root@pubby samba-4.8.3]# samba-tool domain provision
Realm [LOCAL]: Sang.com
 Domain [Sang]: Sang.com
 Server Role (dc, member, standalone) [dc]: 
 DNS backend (SAMBA_INTERNAL, BIND9_FLATFILE, BIND9_DLZ, NONE) [SAMBA_INTERNAL]: 
 DNS forwarder IP address (write 'none' to disable forwarding) [192.168.254.2]: 
Administrator password: 
Administrator password does not meet the default minimum password length requirement (7 characters).
Administrator password: 
Retype password: 
ERROR(<class 'samba.provision.ProvisioningError'>): Provision failed - ProvisioningError: guess_names: 'realm =' was not specified in supplied /etc/samba/smb.conf.  Please remove the smb.conf file and let provision generate it
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/samba/netcmd/domain.py", line 500, in run
    plaintext_secrets=plaintext_secrets)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 2116, in provision
    sitename=sitename, rootdn=rootdn, domain_names_forced=(samdb_fill == FILL_DRS))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 620, in guess_names
    raise ProvisioningError("guess_names: 'realm =' was not specified in supplied %s.  Please remove the smb.conf file and let provision generate it" % lp.configfile)
```

Comment: The last 2 lines are not enough to act upon?  extra questions: you are not using Ubuntu? we do NOT use root when using Ubuntu and  python 2.7 ... well that one is end of life so should be avoided anyways. Maybe time for an upgrade?  18.04 ends end of this month in case you still use that.

Answer (score 0):

First, upgrade, 4.8.3 is well EOL from the Samba point of view. Next, set up your dns correctly, your machine appears to be using '.local', now you may be getting this from Avahi or you could have set it like that, but either way, it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old but the issue and fix seems to be in the first line of the error

> ... 'realm =' was not specified in supplied /etc/samba/smb.conf.
> Please remove the smb.conf file and let provision generate it

Also it looks like you are using sang.com for both realm and domain. Domain should just be sang

Here's some documentation that I found helpful:

[Samba AD Setup](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller)